# Array manipulation in Excel formula arguments

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

my question is pretty specific, and I haven't been able to find a solution. Here's a sample dataset that illustrates the problem:

```
First     Last     Sales     Months
Kevin     Smith    $500      10
Joe       Stevens  $400      6
Frank     Doe      $600      4
```

I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve any computation columns or cells in the final result.

Now lets say I had this list

```
Kevin Smith
Frank Doe
```

I want to sum their sales/month in a separate cell.

I've tried:

> =SUM(SUMIF(CONCATENATE(A1:A3, " ", B1:B3),A5:A6,C1:C3/D1:D3))

Data is stored in rows 1-3 where column A is first name, Column B is last name, Column C is sales, and column D is months. The full names are in A5 and A6.

When I apply the function I have tried both *Enter* and *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*

**Strangely enough, this formula works when I don't do any array concatenation or division in the formula. That's really the crux of this question. Why can't I do the array manipulation in the formula?**

> =SUM(SUMIF(A1:A3,A8:A9,C1:C3))

Unfortunately, in my real life problem, I can't use this workaround.

I tried posting a picture, but even though I've been reading the answers on this site for a long time, I've never posted anything so I have no 'reputation.'

Thank you in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SUMIF` doesn't allow you to apply any functions to the criteria or sum ranges (because that makes them arrays and `SUMIF` only allows ranges)....but you can use a `SUMPRODUCT` formula like this to avoid any extra cells/columns and also avoid "array entry"

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A3&" "&B1:B3,A5:A6,0))+0,C1:C3/D1:D3)`

`MATCH` function matches the concatenated name columns against your names in `A5:A6` and returns either a number (if there's a match) or an error - `#N/A` - if there isn't a match, so applying `ISNUMBER` function to that array gives an array of `TRUE/FALSE` values which +0 converts to `1/0` values. `SUMPRODUCT` then multiplies that array with the C/D division and sums the results, giving the required answer.

You can't have any text in the `C1:C3` or `D1:D3` ranges otherwise you'll get an error

Comment: That's an awesome workaround, thanks, Barry. What if I want to have text in that column?

Comment: Then I would revert to an "array formula" that will filter out any rows with text, e.g. `=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A3&" "&B1:B3,A5:A6,0)*C1:C3/D1:D3),C1:C3/D1:D3))` - confirmed with `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, because of the way the formulas are implemented, you will need additional computational columns, unless you want to do some programming.

To use just a formula, you will need a column for the concatenated names and a column for the amounts to add together (C2/D2). Then you can use the array formula: `=SUM(SUMIF(A1:A3,A8:A9,C1:C3))`